# onchange on dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, ajax

my question is continuation of what i have asked see the link.
[Load Country/State/City](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640001/load-country-state-city)

i have expand to load my drop downs list from db and i just need a way to wire onchange method in my first dropdownlist and second, please see the code. appreciate any help.

***Append latest code:***

```
<select id="country"  onchange="getStateByCountryId()"></select> <br />
<select id="state"></select>  <br />


$(document).ready(function() { 
     var options = {
         type: "POST",
         url: "SearchPage.aspx/LoadCountry",
         data: "{}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",

         success: function(msg) {

             var returnedArray = msg.d;
             country = $("#country"); 
              country.append('<option>Select a Country</option>'); 

             for (i = 0; i < returnedArray.length; i++) {
                  country.append("<option value='" + returnedArray[i].Id + "'>" + returnedArray[i].Name + "</option>");
             }


         }
     };
     $.ajax(options);
 });


function getStateByCountryId() {

     $("#country").change(function() 
     { 
         var _selected = $("#country").val();
         var options = 
         {
             type: "POST",
             url: "SearchPage.aspx/StateBy",
             data: "{'countryId':'" + _selected + "'}",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",

             success: function(msg) {
                $('#state').empty(); 
                 var returnedArray = msg.d;


                 state = $("#state");
                 for (var i = 0; i < returnedArray.length; ++i) {
                     state.append("<option value='" + returnedArray[i].Id + "'>" + returnedArray[i].Name + "</option>");
                 }
             }
         };
         $.ajax(options);
     });
 }
```

but does not populate? the way i am doing is that how you suppose to do?

thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$("#state").change(function(){
    //on-change code goes in here.
    //variable "this" references the state dropdown element
});
```

Comment: how do i get the id of a parent (country) dropdown element?

Comment: "country" is not a "parent" in the HTML above, it's simply another element. The above code, but replacing `#state` with `#country` would get what you want. Or am I misunderstanding? Do you want the "previous" element instead?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).parent("select").attr("id");
```

Comment: under which <select> is the element that you are currently in?  IF you're in an element under the state select, then you would simply do: $("#country").val();

Comment: let me try and get back to you.

Comment: here is the update

i get the value by doing $("#country").val();

okay... when the page load very first time it populates all my country but when i change to other country it does not fire for the first time but it does fire (onchange event) when i change the country second time... why is it?

Comment: i have append the latest code, please have a look at it. - thanks.

Comment: by populating the dropdown using ajax, it's selected value is not getting saved in the viewstate.  Perhaps you could pass the selected value in the querystring on postback so you can re-select the value on page load.